# Would modifying Liouville's Condition for Liouville Numbers lead to proving that more numbers are transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A real number x is a Liouville Number if it satisfies the following condition:

$$0<\left|x-\frac{c}{d}\right|<\frac{1}{d^n}$$

A Liouville number is a transcendental number.

Suppose we were to modify this condition. Let:

$$c=c_n$$

$$d=d_n$$

$$d^n=\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}d_k}$$

You would get:

$$0<|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}|<\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}d_k}$$

Suppose x is an AT number if and only if for every natural number $n$, there exists infinitely many pairs of rational numbers ${(c}_{n,}d_n)$ with $d_n$ not equal to one such that

$$0<|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}|<\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}d_k}$$

If a real x satisfies the modified condition would it be transcendental?

I ask because I want to prove that Apery’s Constant is transcendental by using this modified version of Liouville’s condition for Liouville Numbers:

$$0<\left|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}\right|<\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}d_k}$$

$$x=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{({p_k}^3}-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}$$

$$c_n=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{({p_k}^3}-1)}d_n$$

$$d_n=\frac{{p_n}^3-1}{{p_n}^3}$$

$$0<\left|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}\right|<\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{({p_k}^3}-1)}$$

$$0<\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{({p_k}^3}-1)}\right|<\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{({p_k}^3}-1)}$$.

Suppose that x was a rational number:

$$0<\left|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}\right|>\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}d_k}$$

$$x=3=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}$$

$$c_n=d_n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{3^k}$$

What would $d_n$ equal?

Either it will equal

$$\frac{3}{2} or \frac{2}{3}$$

Suppose $d_n$  equals

$$\frac{2}{3}$$ .

Then

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}d_k}=\frac{1}{\frac{2^n}{3^n}}=\frac{3^n}{2^n}$$

So,

$$0<\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}-\frac{d_n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{3^k}}{d_n}\right|>\frac{3^n}{2^n}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}-\frac{d_n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{3^k}}{d_n}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}$$

So,

$$0<\left|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k}\right|<\frac{3^n}{2^n}$$

Which contradicts our assumption.

So $$d_n$$ has to be the inverse of

$\frac{2}{3}$ in order to work.

Comment: What is $n$ in the definition of Liouville number?

Comment: @coffeemath, n is any number in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @coffeemath, I'm just wondering whether the modification to Liouville's condition is valid.

Comment: So you want to relax the statement to inspecting $$0 < \left|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}\right| < \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n d_j}$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams, is there anything fallacious about the condition?

Comment: @AquinasLover1 no, just restating since your OP is slightly oddly phrased. The $c_n$ condition is particularly perplexing for me.

Comment: On wiki page, a Liouville number $x$  is one such that, for *any* natural number $n$ there are infinitely many pairs $(c,d)$ with $0<|x-c/d|<d^n.$- It confused me that you omitted reference to the need of infinitely many pairs $(c,d)$ in your definition.

Comment: @coffeemath, by wiki page you mean Wikipedia, right?

Comment: @coffeemath, I thought it was $\frac{1}{d^n}$...

Comment: Yes, my bad.. it was $1/d^n$ (and yes by wiki I mean Wikipedia.)

Comment: On second though, I'm not quite understanding what your condition actually *is*. It looks like you are asking for the existence of some sequence of pairs **of integers** $(c_k,d_k)$ such that $0<\lvert x-c_n/d_n\rvert<\prod_{k=1}^n d_k^{-1}$, but then you add that $d^n=\prod_{k=1}^nd_k^{-1}$. What is that supposed to mean? Last I read of it, $d$ was a variable quantified over the an integers (in a completely unrelated sentence). Is that supposed to mean that RHS is the $n$ power of an integer? It's impossible.

Comment: Also, the example you made does not help at all: $d_n=\frac{p_n^3-1}{p_n^3}=1-p_n^{-3}$ does not look like an integer by any means, unless $p_n$ is the reciprocal of an integer.

Comment: @Gae.S, concerning the pair of integers, I used as a reference the Wikipedia article on Liouville Numbers, specifically the section on how to construct them.

Comment: @Gae.S, if you want I can send you my justification as to my thought process in the original post as a separate document. Because I'm limited as to how much I can respond the comments.

Comment: @Gae.S, please check the OP again because I edited it so that x is equal to a rational number.

Comment: I am familiar with Liouville's theorem, I had even written an answer to this post which I had to retract out of the concerns over your definition. It was a bad case of me trying too hard to make sense of something. You have not addressed my concern at all: you just added more stuff. The way to address my concern is to write **exactly** that "weak Liouville" condition of yours. A sample sentence: "$x$ is a Papageno number if and only if, for all $y$ natural numbers, either $y$ is a multiple of $x$ or there is some sequence of rational numbers $\{w_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that, for all ET CETERA"

Comment: @Gae.S., sorry about that. I misunderstood you. Please check the original post again because I edited it to be more upfront about the condition. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I think that an important semantical failure is still there, however the good news is that I grew bored of asking for clarification. I've stated my mind in the form of an answer, which I won't edit or address any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{abs}[1]{\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert}$The following fact is true:

> For all $x\in \Bbb R$ of [irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of strictly larger that $1$, there is an injective sequence of coprime integers $\{(c_n,d_n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $d_n>0$ and $0<\abs{x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}}<\left(\prod_{j=1}^n d_j\right)^{-1}$

*Proof:* Consider some $\alpha>1$ such that the set $A_x$ of coprime pairs of integers $(c,d)$ such that $d>0$ and $0<\abs{x-\frac cd}<d^{-\alpha}$ is infinite. Select $(c_1,d_1)\in A_x$ with $d_1>1$. Now, choose $(c_2,d_2)\in A_x$ such that $\frac1{d_1d_2}>\frac1{d_2^{\alpha}}$: this is possible because $\alpha>1$ and $d_2$ may be chosen to be arbitrarily large. Then, choose $(c_3,d_3)\in A_x$ such that $\frac1{d_1d_2d_3}>\frac1{d_3^\alpha}$: again, this is possible because $\alpha>1$ and $d_3$ may be chosen arbitrarily larger than the previous numbers... and so on by induction, ending up with $$0<\abs{x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}}<\frac1{d_n^\alpha}<\left(\prod_{j=1}^n d_j\right)^{-1}$$ for all $n$.

---

Since the irrational real numbers are exactly the numbers of irrationality measure $\ge2$, such a sequence may be devised for all irrationals.

Comment: **Note:** This answer will not be edited or addressed any further by its author past 1st July 2020, 11:25 GMT

Comment: Gae.S. Thank you! You basically answered my question. I should have specified that c and d were natural numbers with d greater than one. However, I wasn't sure in writing my response to you since I am an amateur mathematician.